# angular universal - prerender adding an extra slash on url

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

we use angular 8 as ssr universal and prerender. Below the code when I use prerender with expressjs, but for some reason after the page is prerendered the urls is adding an an extra slash at the end, which make the page not indexable, then angular makes a redirected javascript to the correct page.

the angular universal prerender page will make the url like

https://www.mywebsite.com/home/

then redirects

https://www.mywebsite.com/home

the first url is the one prerendered

Any ideas why? and what do I need to fix this?

```
      import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
      import 'reflect-metadata';
      import {readFileSync, writeFileSync, existsSync, mkdirSync} from 'fs';
      import {join} from 'path';

      import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
      // Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
      enableProdMode();

      // Import module map for lazy loading
      import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
      import {renderModuleFactory} from '@angular/platform-server';
      import { ROUTESStaticPages } from './prerender-static-pages';


      // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
      const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

      const BROWSER_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'project');

      // Load the index.html file containing referances to your application bundle.
      const index = readFileSync(join('project', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

      let previousRender = Promise.resolve();

      // Iterate each route path
      ROUTESStaticPages.forEach(route => {
        const fullPath = join(BROWSER_FOLDER, route);

        // Make sure the directory structure is there
        if (!existsSync(fullPath)) {
          mkdirSync(fullPath);
        }

        // Writes rendered HTML to index.html, replacing the file if it already exists.
        previousRender = previousRender.then(_ => renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
          document: index,
          url: route,
          extraProviders: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
            { provide: 'APP_BASE_URL', useFactory: () => '123124531254', deps: [] },
            { provide: 'APP_REQ_HEADERS', useFactory: () => JSON.stringify('94384239572'), deps: []},
          ]
        })).then(html => writeFileSync(join(fullPath, 'index.html'), html));
      });
```

and in the ROUTESStaticPages the urls are listed like:

```
      export const ROUTESStaticPages = [
          '/',
          '/home',
          '/login',
          '/login/createlogin',
          '/login/resetpassword',
          '/pages',
          '/pages/about-us',

        ];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: DId you check in your networktab whether this is a redirection? You need to tick the 'preserve logs' checkbox to verify that

Comment: We have the logs enabled and there is no errors

Comment: Yeah, but you navigate to `https://www.mywebsite.com/home`, what is the network response? Is it a 301 redirection?

Comment: When crawled on screamingfrog the status

/home/ 
200 OK 
/home 
301 Moved Permanently

Comment: Check for all redirections in your angular code. If there is nothing, maybe it's added by your reverse proxy if you are using one (e.g. nginx)

Comment: thx, but we don't use a reverse proxy and we use iis, also there is no rule or webconfig to add an extra slash at the end

Comment: Checkout my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835009/5832236 short answer is upgrade Angular Universal above 11.1 and make sure your server routes all traffic to `main.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue in my universal prerender , by default redirect is true on expressjs configuration I have changed to false  is no long redirecting now , [express router config](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html)

```js
app.use(express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), { maxAge: '1y', redirect: false }));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y',
  redirect: false
}));
```

Comment: What about if you want to redirect from 'http' to 'https', you won't with that?

Comment: Hi @AmosIsaila my suggestion for you is, use that library is the easy way in my point view , https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-https-redirect